What is the title of this animated short about a man blinded in an accident?
I'm trying to track down an animated short from the late 1980s or early 1990s. Here are some details:

The plot involves a man who is in an accident (most likely involving a car) where he is temporarily blinded. He has to wear bandages over his eyes while he recovers at home. Whenever he gets into trouble, a woman (who was involved in the accident) appears like an angel and helps him.
The film is in colour, running anywhere from 5 to 15 minutes long.
There is no dialogue; the story is told all through visuals and music.
There may have been a Winter or Christmas element to it.
It mostly takes place at night.
It was shown between movies on a cable pay movie channel.
It may have been affiliated with the Film Board of Canada.


You're looking for the stop-motion short Nightangel from 1986. From IMDb:

The film begins with a man looking outside late at night. He sees some sort of angelic woman with a billowy robe or perhaps wings. He's obviously quite taken with the sight of her and leaves his apartment. Sadly, however as he crosses the road to catch her, he's hit by a car. While not killed, he is temporarily blinded and is briefly hospitalized. When he returns, he tries to take care of himself but is frustrated and ultimately terrified...when suddenly, this angelic creature appears to him--calming him and caring for him.

It was indeed co-produced by the National Film Board of Canada. Here's a still:

